Is it possible to cut a 10cm (4 inches) basil stem and regrow its roots for replanting?
I have a basil plant that got really distressed by repotting it and all the leaves from the lower parts of the stem fell off and the stem itself turned brown. RN its trying to escape its new pot as best as it can.

I'd like to reign it in and cut the tops of the 4 main branches it has from where the green starts, regrow the roots in a jar of water and then plant it back. I know that this is how one can multiply a basil plant, by cutting under each node but I just want to keep the branches whole. The thing is, I don't know if the stems would survive the process as it may be hard to pull enough water for the whole length of it.
So question is, would the basil survive if I do this?
